Setting security level in LFTP
I have a simple LFTP script that I used to run successfully on MacOsx:
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set ftp:ssl-auth TLS;
set ftp:ssl-force true;
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true;
set ftps:initial-prot "";
open -u 'USERNAME','PASSWORD' -pPORT ftp.address.com
lftp -e 'set net:timeout 10; at now; ls ; bye

However, recently I got a Fatal error: SSL_connect: dh key too small.
According to this SO question this might be solved by lowering the security level temporarily.
How can I set
CipherString=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
in my LFTP script?

I do not think you can. As the linked question shows, the CipherString is configured in OpenSSL configuration file.
